# Java OpenGL Text Rendering

Tags: java, opengl, text

I have a GLCanvas on which I want to render some text. I'm actually using a 3rd party library that extends GLCanvas and it is doing most of the GL rendering. The 3rd party tool allows you to display images on it, so I've been creating images of the text and displaying it on the GLCanvas.

That works, except the text doesn't really look to crisp (but if I write the image out to a file it does, so I suspect it has to do with using graphics.drawString on a GLCanvas, but I'm not sure). The 3rd party app gives access to the GL Object, but I only know the position of the text I want to render in x,y screen coordinates, so I'm not sure how to translate that to GL.

I've tried to access the GL Object but I get errors about not having an openGL context current on this thread. I understand what this means, I just don't know if I have access to the thread on which the GL context is running.

Any advice as to how to best render the text?

Comment: Unfortunately, the exact translation from screen coordinates to GL coordinates is dependent on how your third-party tool works; in particular, what parameters it's supplying to `glOrtho()`.  Similar difficulties exist for your OpenGL context problems.  Could you possibly tell us more?

Comment: David, thanks for the reply. What other type of information would be useful here (sorry, my GL knowledge is somewhat limited)? I have full access to the actual GL object (not sure about GLU though).

Comment: Also, I only need to draw in one fixed corner (although the height and width of what I'm drawing may vary, it will always be drawn from a corner of the screen).

Comment: Ah, I figured out the 3rd party tool has some wrappers around the openGL object which I could use to display the text. Thanks.